# Basic Java database

Tags: java, database

I just wrote my first Java database program for the purpose of getting feedback on the implementation and coding. It has 1 table and 2 buttons and prompts the user to select a folder, lists the contents of the folder in the table and lists the hash of the files in the table and writes it to a database.

It works fine, but I have no idea if I coded it cleanly and split the program into the proper packages and classes. It's definitely a beginner level project so there is nothing too complex about it.  I'm also using the h2 database because I was told its the most efficient for small databases.  Could you all please give me feedback on this?

I used NetBeans 7.3 and uploaded the full project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?huujeed8oiwonr8). This is the class I'm using for the database.  It contains most of the code I have in question, but there are other parts of the project as a whole I'm concerned if they were organized correctly:

```
public class CDatabaseLayer {
    private static ArrayList<CFileObject> fileList = new ArrayList();
    private static Server server;
    private static JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    private static Connection conn;
    private static int lastId = 0;
    private static Statement stat;
    private static ResultSet rs;
    private static String query;


    static public ArrayList<CFileObject> getFileList() {
        connectDatabase();
        return fileList;
    }


    static public boolean connectDatabase()
    {
        System.out.println("Attempting to connect to database.");
        if(server == null) {
            try {
                server = Server.createTcpServer();
                server = server.start();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("connectDatabase createTcpServer() exception: "+ex);
                return false;
            }
        }

        //return false if connected
        if(conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Already established DB connection.");
            return false;
        } else {
            try {
                //connect to database
                ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:test");
                ds.setUser("sa");
                ds.setPassword("");

                conn = ds.getConnection();

                if(conn.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("Connection not established.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connected.");
                    createFileListTable();
                    loadFileListTable();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("connectDatabase getConnection() exception: "+ex);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    static private void loadFileListTable()
    {
        try {
            stat = newStatement();
            rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from fileList");
            fileList.clear();

            while(rs.next()) {
                CFileObject objF = new CFileObject();
                objF.fileName = rs.getString("fileName");
                objF.filePath = rs.getString("filePath");
                objF.fileHash = rs.getString("fileHash");
                fileList.add(objF);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("loadFileListTable exception: "+ex);
        }

    }

    static public void manipulateFiles() throws SQLException {        
        try {
            if(conn.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("manipulateFiles: Connection is closed.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("manipulateFiles connection exception: "+ex);
        }

        for(CFileObject f : fileList) {
            String hash = new String();
            try {
                hash = hashFile.getMD5Checksum(f.filePath);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("manipulateFiles hash exception: "+ex);
            }
            f.fileHash = hash;

            query = "update filelist set filehash = '"+hash+"' where filepath = '"+f.filePath+"'";

            stat = newStatement();
            //QUESTION: Why does this return false??
            stat.execute(query);
        }   
    }


    static public void updateDatabaseWithFilesFromPath(File path)
    {
        ArrayList<CFileObject> list;
        list = CFileObject.getListFromPath(path);


        for(CFileObject file : list) {
            if(!entryExists("filelist", "filepath", file.filePath)) {
                try {
                    lastId = nextUnusedId();
                    addFileEntry(lastId, file.fileName, file.filePath);
                    fileList.add(file);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println("updateDatabaseWithFilesFromPath exception: "+ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /*
    static public void updateDatabase() throws SQLException
    {
        lastId = nextUnusedId();

        for (final CFileObject file : fileList) {
            if(!entryExists("filelist", "filepath", file.filePath)) {
                lastId = nextUnusedId();
                addFileEntry(lastId, file.fileName, file.filePath);
            }
        }
    }
    */


    private static Statement newStatement()
    {
        try {
            stat = conn.createStatement();
            return stat;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("newStatement exception: "+ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //QUESTION: Is there a more efficient way to do this?
    private static void createFileListTable()
    {
        try {                    
            //see if fileList table exists.  if not, catch error and create it
            try {
                stat = newStatement();
                stat.executeQuery("select * from fileList");
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                if(e.toString().contains("Table \"FILELIST\" not found")) {
                    System.out.println("Creating filelist table.\n");
                    stat.execute("create table filelist(id int primary key, fileName varchar(255), filePath varchar(512), fileHash varchar(32))");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("createFileListTable exception: "+ex);
        }
    }

    private static int nextUnusedId()
    {
        try {
            stat = newStatement();
            rs = stat.executeQuery("select id from fileList");
            if(rs.last()) {
                lastId = rs.getInt("id");
                lastId++;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("nextUnusedId exception: "+ex);
        }

        return lastId;
    }

    private static boolean entryExists(String table, String prop, String val)
    {
        try {
            stat = newStatement();
            query = "select 1 from "+table+" where "+prop+" = '"+val+"'";
            rs = stat.executeQuery(query);
            return rs.last();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("entryExists exception: "+ex);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void addFileEntry(int entryId, String fileName, String filePath) throws SQLException
    {
        query = "insert into fileList values("+entryId+", '"+fileName+"', '"+filePath+"', 0)";

        stat = newStatement();
        //QUESTION: Why does this return false??
        stat.execute(query);
    }

    static public void disconnectDatabase()
    {
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I noticed after taking a quick look:

1. I'm not a big fan of the static/singleton-ness of this class.  Those attributes make this class harder to mock and unit test.  Take a look at POJO/dependency injection (you don't need a container to do DI).
2. I would consider separating the database/Connection opening stuff into its own class.  There should be separation of what the data access/service layer from the resource/connection code.  Take a look at DAO/Service patterns.
3. getFileList() returns a concrete List implementation instead of the List interface.
4. A lot of your methods don't close the ResultSet and Statement objects once they are done with them.  They should be closed in finally blocks.
5. Your catch blocks aren't doing much besides printing to System.out.  You need to either handle recoverable exceptions there or propogate them up the stack as a RuntimeException.
6. Not sure why you need newStatement().
7. You are manually creating and executing SQL strings.  This is a bad idea.  Replace these with PreparedStatements.
8. This class isn't threadsafe.  It should be documented as much.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  It sounds like I'm doing a lot wrong.  Where can I find proper implementations of simple programs like this?  I learn best through examples and I haven't been able to find any simple tutorials that used databases like this.

Comment: One, pick up a copy of Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, 2nd edition.  It is the definitive book about Java programming and best practices.  Two, here are a couple of links to get you started: [Core J2EE Patterns - Data Access Object](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html), [Data Access object (DAO) Design Pattern](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/dataaccessobjectdesignpattern.html), [JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).